# How to define a function with an array of pointers of a struct as parameter from C to C#

Tags: c#, pinvoke

In C code, the function is defined like:

```
INT WINAPI myFunction(LPCTSTR str1, LPCTSTR str2, INT iNumber,
    LPSTRUCT *lpStruct);
```

`*lpStruct` is an array of pointers of a struct type:

```
typedef struct myStruct
{
CHAR                    m_s1[64];       
UINT                    m_nS;       
CHAR                    m_s2[8][64];    
UINT                    m_nP;
CHAR                    m_s3[512];

} SomeStruct, *LPSTRUCT;
```

I need to call this external `myFunction` in C#, I defined `SomeStruct` as:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct SomeStruct
{

   [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
   public string m_s1;             
   public uint m_nS;             
   [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 512)]
   public string m_s2;             
   public uint m_nP;
   [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 512)]
   public string m_s3;
 }
```

myFunction as:

```
[DllImport("some.dll")]
public static extern int myFunction(
             string str1,
             string str2,
             int iNumber,
             IntPtr[] lpStruct);
```

I initialize IntPtr[] in C#:

```
IntPtr[] lpptr = new IntPtr[iNumber];
```

I know the struct array of pointer has `iNumber` elements.

There is no error to call this function (`lpStruct[i]` has number). But when I tried to Marshal the pointer to the struct using:

```
SomeStruct st = (SomeStruct )Marshal.PtrToStructure(lpStruct[i], 
    typeof(SomeStruct ));
```

I got error message: try to write read-only memory. I don't know what's wrong here. Is the external function definition in C# wrong or the definition of struct wrong, or both.

Comment: What do all the macros expand to? Don't make us guess? What is `TCHAR`? Ansi or Unicode? Does the struct really mix `CHAR` and `TCHAR`? Show how you call `myFunction`. Show how you allocate the `IntPtr[]` before calling. Are you 100% sure that the function returns an array? Or does it just fill out one struct? If it is an array, how long must the array be? Your edits suggest you are posting fake code. Use copy/paste to post the real code. Don't post fake code. The question is missing a lot of critical detail. Do you have sample C code that calls this API? That would help a LOT.

Comment: try `typeof(SomeStruct)` instead of `typeof(lpStruct)`

Comment: Thanks for you comments. I just revised some typo.

Comment: We still need to see how you call the function, where the `IntPtr[]` is allocated, and ideally some sample C code that calls it. Then I'm sure we can get to the bottom of it. What's the deal with `m_s2` by the way?

Comment: I also tried to define the last parameter in myFunction as [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]SomeStruct[] lpStruct, but after run myFunction, the array of SomeStruct I passed didn't change at all.

Comment: Here is how I initialize IntPtr[] in C#: IntPtr[] lpptr = new IntPtr[iNumber]; I know the struct array of pointer has iNumber elements.  Here all the parameters are not real name(use m_s1, m_s2 to replace). But the variable types are correct.

Comment: You have to allocate each member of `lpptr` too surely. Please don't add code in comments. Edit the question to include these details.

Comment: To answer David's question, m_s2 is 8 possible searching results for m_s1 in struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question lacks important details, but I would expect that you need to allocate memory for each IntPtr in the array.

```
IntPtr[] lpptr = new IntPtr[iNumber];
for (int i=0; i<iNumber; i++)
    lpptr[i] = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SomeStruct)));
```

And obviously you should free the memory once you are done with it.

Comment: Thank you, David. It works! I didn't allocate memory for the pointer array.

Comment: Last question for David. When do I don't need to allocate memory for this pointer array?

Comment: I don't understand. The signature of the function demands that the caller allocates the memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the Struct as a class in C#

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
internal class SomeStruct
{

   [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
   public string m_s1;             
   public UInt32 m_nS;             
   [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 512)]
   public string m_s2;             
   public UInt32 m_nP;
   [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 512)]
   public string m_s3;
}
```

also try UInt32 inplace of uint

Comment: UInt32 and uint are the same thing. There's no need to guess at things like that.